# (EVO Cms) Наследование значений ТВ параметров дочерним ресурсом от родительского

Tags: evolution

Начинающий разработчик на evo cms. Есть каталог с 3 уровнями вложенности, у каждого уровня есть одинаковые тв-параметры (width, hight,long). Хочу добавить функциональность, при заполнении тв-параметров у верхнего (родительского) элемента всем дочерним элементам, у которых данные тв-параметры не заполнены, присвоить значения этих же параметров из родителя. Думаю что для этого нужен плагин на событие onDocFormSave. Видел топик где обсуждалась обратная зависимость, хочется узнать как сделать именно такую (родитель -> дочерний ресурс)

Думаю что нужно создать плагин и повесить ему событие OnDocFormSave

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.